# How to add animation to shift view?

Tags: ios, swift

I have code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var rightMenuViev: UIView!
var rightMenuVisible = false

func showAndHideRightMenu(){
        if rightMenuVisible == false{
            var rightMenu = rightMenuViev.frame
            rightMenu.origin.x = rightMenu.origin.x + 155
            rightMenuViev.frame = rightMenu

            rightMenuVisible = true
        } else{
            var rightMenu = rightMenuViev.frame
            rightMenu.origin.x = rightMenu.origin.x - 155
            rightMenuViev.frame = rightMenu

            rightMenuVisible = false
        }
    }
```

The above code is supposed to hide the side menu and show it depending on the rightMenuVisible status.
Everything works fine, but I would like to add an animation that shifts the menu.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For animation you can use `UIView.animate...` methods.

```
func showAndHideRightMenu() {

    if rightMenuVisible == false{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

            var rightMenu = rightMenuViev.frame
            rightMenu.origin.x = rightMenu.origin.x + 155
            rightMenuViev.frame = rightMenu

            rightMenuVisible = true

        }) { (isCompleted) in
            //code after animation completion
        }

    } else{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            var rightMenu = rightMenuViev.frame
            rightMenu.origin.x = rightMenu.origin.x - 155
            rightMenuViev.frame = rightMenu

            rightMenuVisible = false

        }) { (isCompleted) in
            //code after animation completion
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let originalTransform = self.main.transform
let scaledTransform = originalTransform.scaledBy(x: 0.2, y: 0.2)
let scaledAndTranslatedTransform = scaledTransform.translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -250.0)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
    self.main.transform = scaledAndTranslatedTransform
})
```